# Facing NoSuchMethodError for HttpRequest setResponseReturnRawInputStream

Tags: google-api, google-bigquery, httprequest

From the past few days I've been getting this error

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpRequest.setResponseReturnRawInputStream(Z)Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpRequest;
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.buildHttpRequest(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:442)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:549)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.executeUnparsed(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:482)
    at com.google.api.client.googleapis.services.AbstractGoogleClientRequest.execute(AbstractGoogleClientRequest.java:599)
```

The code where the error is occuring:

```
Table fetchedTable = bigQueryService.tables().get(tableRef.getProjectId(), tableRef.getDatasetId(), tableRef.getTableId()).execute();
```

The weird thing is I've been using this same code for the past year without any issues. No jars were updated nothing. I'm unable to find anything on the internet too.

It would mean a lot if anyone could help.

Thanks :)

Comment: Which version of jars are you using?

Comment: @plaidshirt - v2-rev438-1.25.0 of google-api-services-bigquery